# Altium: what layers these parts in this picture are?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, footprint, pcb-layers

I'm going to create foot print of D-sub sdf-us91-95. in its datasheet this picture of holes is shown. but what are the layers of others and generally what are they?
[image]

Comment: Those are mounting holes and slots, not signal pins.

Comment: These seem to be holes, does it help: http://www.eevblog.com/forum/altium/methods-for-making-a-pcb-mounting-hole-in-altium-designer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to me that the 1.6mm and 2.1mm alignment holes are intended to receive plastic pins molded into the connector. In this case, they should **not** have a pad and should be **unplated**.

The **slots** receive snaps made of solderable metal, and should be of the indicated dimensions and have pads and paste layer suitable for the soldering technology used (either wave or paste-in-hole). Most PCB makers will make these using drilled slot method for a double-side or multilayer board.

I would suggest having a sample on hand of this, and any other unfamiliar component, to check the footprint before sending it off.

Some of the online datasheets carry this warning:

[image]

Comment: So do you mean that inner red circles should not be mentioned necessarily in PCB layout ?

Comment: They should be part of the footprint, for sure . If you don't have holes in the board you won't be able to mount the connector without cutting the pins off (which would defeat their purpose).

Comment: thanks a lot. eventually what layer should be the slots?

Comment: The slots are just part of the pads- multilayer pads with 'Hole Information'  slot and the specified width and length.

Comment: another question has made in my mind is : about the nine pins in the picture, some of them have a dot in the center and others don't. do you know why?

Comment: No. Could just be an artifact of format conversion. #8 doesn't even look like its in the center.

Answer (score 1):

This is a through-hole connector with Pin-In-Paste Technology.  This technology is also called through-hole reflow technology.

The outer red circles in your picture is your grounding board lock clips and therefore the surface of the PCB will need to include holes with isolation to mount this D-sub connector properly.

The inner red circles are pins for alignment purpose.  You will need to design 2 holes in your PCB with the right radius and center to align your part properly.

Hope this helps!

[image: D-sub Connector]

Comment: Actually i didn't understand well about outer circles. do you mean i should deal with them as mounting holes? and excuse me i am somehow new to design PCB, would you explain to me what do you mean by holes with isolation, do you mean this should be connected to ground plane?

Comment: Yes those are mounting holes.  And sorry I should have mentioned that the mounting clip should be connected to a chassis ground.  It would be very similar to plastic mounting clip for a PCB.  You would need to create a hole with a certain radius to attach different PCBs.